# Address of variable i

Tags: c, pointers

I just started learning pointers in C programming. I came across %p,%u format specifiers.  Whenever I use %u it displays a warning, and always changes the output and when I use %p it displays the address of a variable i, but changes it always.  Why does this happen; can anyone explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=3;
    int *j;
    j=&i;
    printf("Address of i= %p\n",&i);
    printf("Address of i=%p\n",&j);
}
```

And please bear with me; I have just started to learn C and programming.  For instance, I literally have no coding experience except html.

Comment: What is the question? Why it prints a different address every time you run the program?

Comment: `int i;` is a variable that needs to be stored somewhere in memory. It can have any `int` value. `i` is stored in `&i`. `int *j;` is also a variable that needs to be stored somewhere in memory. It can have any `int*` value. `j` is stored in `&j`. In your example code the value of `i` will be `3`, while the value of `j` will be `&i` (ie the address of `i`). But `i` and `j` are stored in a different place in memory (so `&i` is different from `&j`).

Comment: @Harshal - To be on the safe side, a pointer ought to be cast to `(void*)` when used with `%p`, because a `void*` and an `int*` doesn't *necessarily* have to be the same size.

Comment: @BoP Not just "*ought to be*", but per the ISO spec it "*shall be*" (a [strict requirement](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4)) - otherwise its UB.

Answer (score 3):

You assigned the address of `i`, i.e. `&i`, to the variable `j`.  Therefore, `&i` and `j` should have the same value:

```
    printf("Address of i = %p\n", (void *) &i);
    printf("Value of j = %p\n", (void *) j);
```

The expression `&j`, on the other hand, is the *address* of the variable `j`, not its value.  Since it resides at a different address from `i`, `&i` and `&j` should be different.

Answer (score 0):

In C programming, `%p` is used to display pointers in their hexadecimal memory address format, while `%u` is used to display unsigned integers.

When you use `%u` to format a pointer, you tell `printf` to interpret the pointer as an unsigned integer and display it as such. This is not the correct way to display pointers. It can give unexpected results and warnings because pointers are not the same as unsigned integers. Pointers are used to hold memory addresses, and treating them as unsigned integers can lead to incorrect values being displayed.

`%p` is the correct format specifier for displaying pointers. When you use `%p`, `printf` will correctly interpret the argument as a pointer and display it in a hexadecimal memory address format. However, output will always change, because the memory address of a variable can change each time you run your program. So, it's normal for the address of the variable `i` to change each time you run your program.

Comment: The character sequence produced by `%p` is [implementation defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) ([ISO C11 §7.21.6.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)).

Answer (score 0):

`&i` varies each time you run the program because the program loader deliberately starts the stack at a random location each time to make it harder for attackers to exploit bugs in programs.